# WAS Liberty Profile won't run external process (using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) )

Tags: servlets, websphere-liberty

As the title suggests, WLP won't run the process- it won't return anything to the process input stream nor to error stream.
If anyone knows about a configuration that needs to take place I would love to know..
(note the process Can run by running the command manually - in addition, the whole thing runs smooth on tomcat8 so..)

---

**EDIT 1:**
The problem was not the command execution under WLP as you guys stated, so I accepted the answer.

The problem is different : I sent a media file to a multipart servlet and stored it in a file on disk using the following code:

```
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();

    String currentTime = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
    String fileName = PATH + currentTime + "." + fileType;
    File file = new File(fileName);

    // write the image to a temporary location
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];            
    while(true) {
        int numRead = is.read(buffer);
        if(numRead == -1) {
            break;
        }
        os.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        os.flush();
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
```

and the file gets saved along with the following prefix:
[image]

While this does not happen on tomcat8 (using the same client).. 
something is not trivial in the received input stream. (Note its a multipart servlet that set up via @MultipartConfig only)

Hope this post will help others..

guys,thanks for your help!

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec isn't an API Liberty in anyway gets involved in so it seems strange that it wouldn't work. What code are you using, how is it failing?

Comment: I'm running a command line application that should create me a text file as output. i'm running the command with 2 arguments. It fails by not running it at all , so there is no new file waiting for me.. (note1: I've tried many many different ways to escape the strings,none succeded) (note2: It must work since I plot the command to the log stream, and if I run it in shell, it does what it should) - and as said before, it runs on tomcat8 - I know its super wierd..

Comment: @Li3ro can you post a stack trace and/or exception message?

Comment: @aguibert , no exception is thrown.. I need to try and run this against a batch file that just echo something.. to make sure this basic thing happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in Liberty.  I was able to test out the following code in a servlet and it printed the path of my current directory just fine:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

Start with a simple command like this, and when you move up to more complex commands or scripts, make sure you are not burying exceptions that may come back.  Always at least print the stack trace!